# Solving maximization problem with linear-fractional sum

Tags: nonlinear-programming, socp

I want to solve this problem :

> **Maximize** \begin{equation} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i}{a_ix_i + b_i}\end{equation} with the constraints \begin{equation}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = S  \ , \ x_i \geq 0 \ \forall \ i \end{equation}
> where $ a_1 , ... , a_n , b_1 , ... , b_n , S > 0$ are known .

Note that the functions \begin{equation}f_i(t) = \frac{t}{a_it + b_i} \end{equation} are strictly increasing and concave on $ (0 , \infty) $

How can I solve this?

Comment: Linear-fractional Programming - conversion to Linear Programming problem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming#Transformation_to_a_linear_program

Comment: For the transformation suggested by @MarkL.Stone, note that you will need a separate $t_i$ for each summand that appears in the objective.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone Thank you for your response . But how can I apply this method if I want to maximize a sum of linear fractions not only one linear fraction ?

Comment: @RobPratt Could you give more details please ? From the wikipedia page it seems this method works for linear fractions but my objective is a sum of linear fractions . Is there are more general method ?

Comment: Sorry, what I suggested does not work when you have constraints across $i$.  Without that constraint $\sum_i x_i=S$, you would multiply numerator and denominator of each summand by a new variable $t_i$, introduce $y_i$ to represent the product $t_i x_i$, and maximize $\sum_i y_i$ subject to $a_i y_i+b_i t_i=1$, $t_i \ge 0$, and $y_i \ge 0$.

Comment: This can be reformulated as a second-order cone programming problem.  Would that help you?

Comment: @RobPratt Any method is good for me . Ideally I want to find a solver that can solve this type of problem .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a second-order cone formulation, obtained by rewriting the objective function as $$\sum_i \frac{1}{a_i} \left(1 - \frac{b_i}{a_i x_i + b_i}\right)$$ and introducing $z_i$ to represent the denominator and $y_i$ to represent $1/z_i$:
\begin{align}
&\text{maximize} &\sum_i \frac{1}{a_i} (1 - b_i  y_i) \\
&\text{subject to} & \sum_i x_i &= S \\
&& z_i &= a_i x_i + b_i &&\text{for all $i$}\\
&& w &= \sqrt 2 \\
&& 2 y_i z_i &\ge w^2 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1\\
&& x_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$}\\
&& y_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} is a rotated second-order cone constraint.  Everything else is linear.

---

**Update:** The reformulation above arose from the development version of a new conic transformation feature in SAS, available in production today.  The following SAS code demonstrates the automatic transformation from algebraic form:

```
/* generate random input data */
%let n = 3;
%let s = 2;
data indata;
   do i = 1 to &n;
      a = rand('UNIFORM');
      b = rand('UNIFORM');
      output;
   end;
run;

proc optmodel;
   /* declare parameters and read data */
   set OBS;
   num a {OBS};
   num b {OBS};
   read data indata into OBS=[i] a b;

   /* declare optimization problem */
   var X {OBS} >= 0;
   max Objective = sum {i in OBS} (1 / a[i]) * (1 - b[i] / (a[i] * X[i] + b[i]));
   con C: sum {i in OBS} X[i] = &s;

   /* optionally expand reformulated problem */
   expand / conic;

   /* call conic solver (automatically reformulating under the hood) */
   solve with conic;

   /* print solution */
   print a b X;
quit;
```

Comment: Great answer . I implemented this method in cvxpy and it gives the right maximum . Thanks !

Comment: @ghiloka If using CVXPY (or CVX), you can directly use `inv_pos`, which will do the SOCP formulation for you under the hood, including adding any needed auxiliary variables. I.e., you will essentially input  (what in CVX would be) objective  `sum(1/a.*(1-b.*inv_pos(a.*x+b)))` and constraints `sum(x) == S` and `x >= 0`, and let CVX(PY) handle the rest. under the hood.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I updated my answer to demonstrate similar newly added functionality in SAS.

Comment: Maybe it's time to update the company and product names to SOAS. Statistical and Optimization Analysis System.  Good to see you are on the road to being a conehead.

Comment: @ghiloka, do you mind sharing your python solution? I have a similar problem to solve (except mine has `c*x` at the numerator), but I have troubles translating the solution into working CVXPY code... I've created a room where we could further discuss, if you will be so kind to share it https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141441/solving-maximization-problem-with-linear-fractional-sum